scikit maad ACI
I noticed, regarding the ACI calculation in skicit maad , that it usually ranges between 300-500  while in other publications (with seewave or soundecology calculations)  it ranges around to 1800.
Is there a difference in the calculation (i.e. the time sample rate maybe?)
Thanks in advance

This seems like a question that is either best posed to the authors of the respective software, or directly answered yourself. One could answer it themself by either inspecting the code (all packages appear to have source code available), and/or running the same dataset through each software package and comparing the results.

Adding up to what Brian said, I'd suggest you post this questions to https://wildlabs.net/discussion/scikit-maad-community .

Hi Dominik and Brian, thank you for your suggestions. I have inspected the code an will contact the scikit maad community , I was not aware of this forum, so thank you!
